# Radon-Nikodym derivative composed with function

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading a paper and it seems to use the following fact, which I am having difficulty in showing rigorously. I will write out my attempt, and any remarks would be appreciated.

Suppose we have two measures $\mu\ll \nu$, and a map $F:Y\to Y$ such that $F$, $F^{-1}$ are both measurable. The paper uses the fact that $\dfrac{d\mu}{d\nu}\circ F=\dfrac{d\mu\circ F}{d\nu\circ F}$ where $\mu\circ F(A)=\mu(F(A))$ for $A$ measurable (similarly for $\nu\circ F$). This is what I will attempt to prove.

It feels as if the natural way to show these are equal (up to $\nu\circ F$-null sets), is this following: Suppose our underlying measurable space is $(Y,\Sigma)$. Let $A\subset Y$ be measurable. Then $\nu\circ F$ restricts to a measure on $\Sigma\cap A=\{B\cap A \mid B\in\Sigma\}\subset 2^A$. Similarly, $\nu$ restricts to a measure on $\Sigma\cap F(A)\subset 2^{F(A)}$. Moreover, $F:(A,\Sigma\cap A)\to (F(A),\Sigma\cap F(A))$ is measurable. Since $F_*\left(\nu\circ F\right)=\nu$, we have by the change of variables formula, that $\mu\circ F(A)=\mu(F(A))=\int\limits_{F(A)}\dfrac{d\mu}{d\nu}\,d\nu=\int\limits_A\left(\dfrac{d\mu}{d\nu}\circ F\right)d\nu\circ F.$

Uniqueness (up to null sets) of the Radon-Nikodym derivative gives the result.

Is this the correct way to do it? Or are there any shortcuts available which I could use?

(PS: Another possible method is to do the above method for $A=Y$, and then for general $A$ use the result for $Y$, plugging in the indicator function of $F(A)$ where necessary).

Any other method would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This looks ok to me. Why do you think $F^{-1}$ need not be measurable, though? If you drop it, I think you need to require instead that $F$ sends measurable sets into measurable sets.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. Thanks for that!