# Radon-Nikodym derivative composed with a measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, radon-nikodym

I was trying to understand the proof given in this question: [Radon-Nikodym derivative composed with function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2488154/radon-nikodym-derivative-composed-with-function#)

Especially the last equality:
$$ \int_{F(A)} \frac{d\mu}{d\nu} \, d\nu = \int_A (\frac{d\mu}{d\nu} \circ F) \, d\nu\circ F $$

I can see that:
$$ \int_{F(A)} \frac{d\mu}{d\nu} \, d\nu = \int_{F(A)} (\frac{d\mu}{d\nu} \circ F) \, d\nu\circ F $$

Since $F_*(\nu\circ F)=\nu$. However, I can’t see why we could exchange to an integral over A, as opposed to this integral over F(A).

Can someone explain to me this part? Is this result true at all? If not, is there another similar result for a composition of a Radon-Nikodym derivative with a measurable function?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you make a change of variable in a definite integral? Don't you change the interval of integration also?

Comment: You're right! my bad. Thanks!!